# Need to Check whether password contains same sequence of characters of UserName in JAVA/ATG

Tags: java, atg, atg-dynamo

I am working on an ATG project.
My requirement is "the password should not contain the same sequence of characters as in UserName".
For eg. If the userName is abcdef@123.com.
Then pw should not be def@123.com
The pw should not include same SEQUENCE of characters.
It can have the characters as in userName. But the ordering/sequence of characters shouldnot be the same.

How can I check this?

Thanks,
Treesa

Comment: This sounds like a dubious requirement. If my username is 'Treesa@stackoverflow.com' even my password can't be 'TopSecret' as it contains an 'r' and 'e' in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to check if the password contains any sequence of the username :

```
public Boolean containsSequences(String uname, String pwd){
  Boolean contains=false;
  int count=0;
  for (String seq: uname.split("/[\@\-\.\_]/g")){ //split the username following this regex.
     if(pwd.indexOf(seq)>0){
        count++;
     }
  }
  if(count>0){
     contains=true;
  }
  return contains;
}
```

This method takes two strings(username and pwd) in input, then takes the sub-sequences of the username and test if the pwd contains one of them, if so then return `true` menas that the pwd contains a sequence of the username.

Or much better you could do:

```
 public Boolean containsSequences(String uname, String pwd){
  Boolean contains=false;
  for (String seq: uname.split("/[\@\-\.\_]/g")){ 
     if(pwd.contains(seq)|| pwd.contains(seq.toUpperCase())|| pwd.contains(seq.toLowerCase())){
        contains=true;
        break;
     }
  }
  return contains;
}
```

Comment: What about CaseSensitivity?

Comment: @radimpe yes good point. I just Edited my answer to check this.

Answer (score -2):

use passowrdString.contains(userNameString)

Comment: This will only confirm that the password contains the entire username, which is not what the original question states.