# Check specific text pattern of password contains in username for javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, regex

username = "Npasandarshana@gmail.com"

password = "S@pasan123"

According to above example, string pattern "pasan" contains in the username.

I want to check whether all password or part of password contains in username for form validating before registration

i used javascript search function as below

```
password.search(username) == '-1'
```

but It searches whole password string in the username and it is not accurate.

Can I use a regex pattern to check some scenario like above in javascript?

Comment: [**Here is a Java solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761643/need-to-check-whether-password-contains-same-sequence-of-characters-of-username). You can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)  is sometimes used for this purposes

Comment: @Mistalis that solution doent give correct answer for me

Comment: According to Java solution  when I split the username  I get 3 substrings "Npasandarshana"   "gmail"  "com"

but non of them contains password = "S@pasan123" in all of those substrings.but part of text in password "pasan" is contained in first substring.According to java logic that doesnt check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the string with `a-z` then .`Array#filter` the length above 4 and `username` contains

```js
function check(use,pwd){
return pwd.match(/[a-z]+/ig).filter(a=> a.length > 4 && use.includes(a)).length > 0? true:false;
}
console.log(check("Npasandarshana@gmail.com","S@pasan123"))//true
console.log(check("Npasandarshana@gmail.com","S@pasysan123"))//false
```

Answer (score 0):

**RegExp**

```
var string = "foo",
    expr = /oo/;
if(expr.test(string)){
    console.log('Yes');
}else{
    console.log('No')
}
```

**Match**

```
var string = "foo",
    expr = "/oo/";
if(string.match(expr)){
    console.log('Yes');
}else{
    console.log('No')
}
```

**(ES6) includes**

```
var string = "foo",
    substring = "oo";
if(string.includes(substring)){
    console.log('Yes');
}else{
    console.log('No')
}
```

Also refer: [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)